# How to create Solidity smart contract that can accept exactly 5 Ether from any sender?

Tags: solidity, ether

If amount is not exactly 5 Ether it has to be refunded back to the sender.

Comment: this question is too general, because is a javascript code and  you can do this with a simple condition like the others types of programming languages... check solidity documentation for learn something abaout "how you can program with solidity"

Answer (score 3):

You can add this condition in your Solidity function like this -

```
function foo() returns(return type) {
    if (msg.value != 5 ether) {
        throw;
    }
    // function definition
    }
```

The function would throw if sent value is not exactly equal to 5 ether.

or you can create a modifier and use it in your function so that condition can be checked before function execution -

```
modifier CheckValue() { 
    if (msg.value != 5 ether) throw; 
    _; 
}

function foo() CheckValue returns(returntype) {
    // function definiton
}
```

Hope this helps.